# Help justifying a conditional variance step?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, central-limit-theorem

The problem runs:  "The count of claims $N$ obeys a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$; the amount per claim $X$ obeys an exponential distribution of mean $\theta$.  Let the variable $S$ be the total amount of $n$ claims [thus $E(S) = E(NX)$].  Conditional on $\lambda$, $\theta$, $X$ and $N$ are independent of each other.  Compute the variance of $S$."

1. Law of Total Variance:  $var(S) = E(var(S|\theta, \lambda)) + var(E(S|\theta, \lambda))$ (OK);
2. The solution stumps me here: $var(S|\lambda, \theta) = E(N|\lambda)var(X|\theta) + var(N|\lambda)E(X|\theta)^2$.

Could someone justify the equation in (2)?  It looks like a mish-mash of the Central Limit Theorem and the formula for $var(XY)$ when $X$, $Y$ are independent, but I can't tease out the reasoning here, and at this point I'm butting my head against the desk.  (I omitted the rest of the solution, which makes sense once that line is accepted.)

For reference, $var(XY) = E(X^2)var(Y) + E(Y^2)var(X) + var(X)var(Y)$ is the formula I refer to above.

Comment: It seems that it should $var(S \vert \lambda, \theta) = E(N^2 \vert \lambda) var(X \vert \theta) + var(N \vert \lambda) {E(X \vert \theta)} ^ 2$. Was there a typo ---- $E(N ^ 2 \vert \lambda)$ rather than $E(N \vert \lambda)$?

Comment: Some further research led me to the answers I needed; sorry if this was redundant, it appears I just didn't have the right search terms:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44719/variance-of-compound-distributions
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution

Apropos of this, it's somewhat annoying that the Formalistic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formalism_(philosophy_of_mathematics) rules of Expectation and Variance never get clearly laid out in a textbook.  It would be an awful help.

Comment: In compound Poisson,each claim, say, $X_1,X_2,...,X_N$, would be independently drawn from some distribution - which is different from  $S=NX$  (which feels a rather strange  model in any case)

Comment: @JuhoKokkala that was a sloppy mistake; I meant it was true under expectation.  I've made the correction above.

Comment: So, if it's all clear to you now, please post an answer to your own question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution), as ever, has a proof (which I'm reiterating):

1. $var_S(S) = E_N(var_{S|N}(S)) + var_N(E_{S|N}(S))$;
2. $var_S(S) = E_N(N*var_X(X)) +var_N(E_X(X)N) $;
3. $var_S(S) = E(N)var(X) + E(X)^2var(N) $ (from the rule that $var_X(aX) = a^2var(X) $).

I suppose it's inadmissible to do this with $X$ since, in the individual risk model (whence this problem), it makes no sense to assume that $X_1, ..., X_n$ are all identical.

Comment: If this answers the question, please mark it as "accepted" (the green V icon), so we all know that it is. It's okay to accept your own answer.